# Wildfly Default data source class name

Tags: wildfly

I am using WildFly 11, I am trying to understand when we configure a data source with a specific driver and we don't set the data source class name explicitly, which actual implementation of `javax.sql.DataSource` does WF ends up using ?

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDB" pool-name="myDB" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" spy="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;useSSL=false</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <background-validation-millis>10000</background-validation-millis>
                    </validation>
</datasource>
```

my application certainly works and I can see the interaction with the DB just fine, however I am not sure which actual datasource implementation is in use, I tried to configure a logger against MySQL packages that contains the default data sources, but nothing seems to get logged as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WildFly is using ironjacamar (http://www.ironjacamar.org/) as its datasource implementation.